# PHP and html in the same html page

Tags: php, html

I have a php file "send.php":

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "RegisterDB";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     } 
    $n=$_POST["name"];
    $a=$_POST["age"];
    $g=$_POST["gender"];
    $gr=$_POST["graduate"];
    $ad=$_POST["address"];
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO RegTbl (name, age, gender,graduate,address)VALUES      ('".$n."','".$a."','".$g."','".$gr."','".$ad."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

and a html file form.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="send.php">
    Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
    Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br><br>
    Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input     type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br><br>
    Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br><br>
    Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send"/>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

And i am trying to embed both codes in a single html page:

```
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $dbname = "RegisterDB";
     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      } 
      $n=$_POST["name"];
      $a=$_POST["age"];
      $g=$_POST["gender"];
      $gr=$_POST["graduate"];
      $ad=$_POST["address"];
      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
      $sql = "INSERT INTO RegTbl (name, age, gender,graduate,address)VALUES ('".$n."','".$a."','".$g."','".$gr."','".$ad."')";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
       } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
      }
       }
     ?>
     <html>
     <body>
     <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
      Name <input type="text" name="name"/><br><br>
      Age <input type="text" name="age"/><br><br>
      Gender <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male"/> M <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female"/> F<br><br>
      Graduate <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="yes"/> YES <input type="radio" name="graduate" value="no"/> NO<br><br>
       Address <textarea name="address"></textarea><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send"/>
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

But this is not working, can anybody help me to find the error? and i save this third file as test.html

Comment: save this third file as test.php file

Comment: Save third file into .php extension. It will work...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute php in an html file. Save the file with the .php extension.

Comment: That's not correct. You can execute .html files as php scripts quite easily: just add `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm` to your `.htaccess` file

Comment: True, but in my opinion a workaround/hack and rather unnecessary.

Comment: It's not a workaround, nor a hack. It's sometimes done to hide what server-side technology is used (security reasons). The downside is that standard html files will first be passed to php, only for it to do nothing at all. As a safety precaution, it's acceptable but a bit redundant considering the downsides.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your php code in html and save the file as .html while running the html file the action will be required on a database which can be done only through php as php is server side and html is client side. So you need a server to run that which in your case is the localhost so you just save the file as .php and run it on the server so that your page can diretly interact with database.

Answer (score 0):

Save it as test.php and run it. Because in html file php doesnt work

Comment: How can this help? Can you give some more information?